# String formatting of nested python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary that prints well

```
print(
    """{ASSET_EDGE_CONFIG[EndAdvertiserAdAccounts][hive_data_features][rev_28d]}""".format(**locals())
)
```

But I want to parametrize 'EndAdvertiserAdAccounts' key to something like below

```
EDGE = 'EndAdvertiserAdAccounts'
print(
    """{ASSET_EDGE_CONFIG[{EDGE}][hive_data_features][rev_28d]}""".format(**locals())
)
```

above code gives me following error:

```
KeyError: '{EDGE}'
```

I guessing there is a particular way to formatting dict using format function. Any help is appreciated here

Comment: Why are you using such complex string formatting and `locals`? Is there something in your use case which could not be achieved instead by computing the value first and then printing it? That would be a more typical approach.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is not possible with the string format function. As Ming points out you're using string format in a very odd way. The specification for string format is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). What you're asking about is basically the `element_index` specification which says the stuff inside the square braces has to either be an integer or string constant. Your example would try to do `ASSERT_EDGE_CONFIG["{EDGE}"]...

If this is all you're trying to do then the following would make better sense:

```
print ASSET_EDGE_CONFIG[EDGE]["hive_data_features"]["rev_28d"]
```

Assuming the more likely case that you're trying to do something more interesting it would be worth giving a more complicated example to show us why you want to use string format.

If you really wanted I guess you could do (requires two format calls):

```
EDGE = 'EndAdvertiserAdAccounts'
print(
    """{{ASSET_EDGE_CONFIG[{EDGE}][hive_data_features][rev_28d]}}""".format(**locals()).format(**locals())
)
```